# Underpinning concrete slab in garage

Tags: concrete, foundation, slab

I am looking at buying a property with a raised section in the garage with a concrete floor. This is a garage entirely seperate from the house. The earth under the end of the slab has fallen away:

[image: Concrete slab with earth fallen away]

[image: Wider view of room with slab in it]

How would I go about stabilising/supporting the slab? I assume I will need to build a retaining wall and backfill it.

Comment: A wider angle picture showing more context would help a lot, but TBH, I think this calls for professional remediation. Is the stone wall in good shape or will it need work? What are the 4 concrete steps to the right of the pic? How thin is that slab? How much house is above this? If you don't know the answers to those, it could end up rather poorly...

Comment: Fallen away? That looks deliberately excavated to me. What's the purpose of that space?

Comment: Well, yes and no.  That CMU wall on the right looks like it should go down that far, but the undermining of the slab is definitely not deliberate.  OP, if you want to keep the "hole" you should build a retaining wall (probably block, so you can backfill with aggregate as you go up).  You may need to wall off the right side too—can't tell if that's a concrete wall with dirt on it, or bare earth.

Comment: This looks far to serious for a DIY project unless you have experience in foundation and concrete work.  This should be left to professionals that have experience and knowledge of the terrain of the area and how it reacts.  You can use this as bargaining material if you are still thinking of purchasing.

Comment: @FreeMan I have added some more details and another image.